# Microsoft access "data type mismatch in criteria expression" error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have written code to add and edit data in a table but I am getting *"data type mismatch in criteria expression"*.

```
Private Sub Submit_Click()

 If Me.txtid.Tag & "" = "" Then
        'add data to table
        CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Client(Client_ID,Title,First_Name,Last_Name,Employer,DOB,Updated_Date,Email,Phone_Number,Mobile_Number,Address_Street,Date_of_1st_Session,Presenting_Issue,Next_Of_Kin,EAP_Number,Status,History)" & _
        " VALUES('" & Me.txtid & "','" & Me.txt_title & "','" & Me.txtname & "','" & Me.txtlastname & "','" & Me.txtorg & "','" & Me.CreatedDate & "','" & Me.UpdatedDate & "','" & Me.txtEmail & "', '" & Me.txtphone & "','" & Me.txtmb & "', '" & Me.txtadd & "','" & Me.txtdate & "', '" & Me.txtissue & "','" & Me.txtnext & "','" & Me.txtEAP & "','" & Me.Combo45 & "','" & Me.txtHistory & "')"
 Else
      CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Client" & " SET Client_ID=" & Me.txtid & ", Title='" & Me.txt_title & "'" & ", First_Name='" & Me.txtname & "'" & ", Last_Name='" & Me.txtlastname & "'" & ", Employer='" & Me.txtorg & "'" & ", DOB='" & Me.CreatedDate & "'" & ", Updated_Date='" & Me.UpdatedDate & "'" & ", Email='" & Me.txtEmail & "'" & ", Phone_Number='" & Me.txtphone & "'" & ", Mobile_Number='" & Me.txtmb & "'" & ", Address_Street='" & Me.txtadd & "'" & ", Date_of_1st_Session='" & Me.txtdate & "'" & ", Presenting_Issue='" & Me.txtissue & "'" & ", Next_Of_Kin='" & Me.txtnext & "'" & ", EAP_Number='" & Me.txtEAP & "'" & ", Status='" & Me.Combo45 & "'" & ", History='" & Me.txtHistory & "'" & " WHERE Client_ID=" & Me.txtid.Tag
 End If

 Command39_Click
 Me.txtid.SetFocus
 Client_subform.Form.Requery
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be treating all the values as strings ('" & Me.txtid & "')when some of the data items may be numeric or dates.
Try ( " & Me.txtid & " ) if it's numeric or (#" & Me.CreatedDate & "#)